# Load MS OneNote file in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, onenote

I'm trying to load an MS OneNote file in WebView but all is in vain. I am finding it hard to do so. Rather I tried another approach. I got the MS OneNote file data and wrote it into an "pdf" file using "writeToFile". But still was not able to load the pdf converted file. Is there any way to load MS OneNOte directly on webview or any way to convert it to pdf format programmatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and open the file using the [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) it will display most files, I haven't tried it with a OneNote file though. [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it was not that useful to me